# Problems with CMake and -DDISABLE_OS_CHECK and missing Git

Tags: git, cmake, makefile

I am trying to install libpng and grib_api on my Windows 10 computer. I already have Cygwin installed

For grib_api, I downloaded version 1.14.0-Source and followed the instructions here: https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/GRIB/GRIB+API+CMake+installation

The makefile and everything for it is in my directory `C:/users/username/desktop/grib_api-1.14.0-Source/grib_api-1.14.0-Source`. After creating the `build`, I then typed

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFILX=C:/users/username/desktop/grib_api-1.14.0-Source/grib_api-1.14.0-Source
```

Here is the output I got on Cygwin

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
```

..

```
-- ecbuild   1.8.0      /cygdrive/c/users/username/desktop/grib_api-1.14.0-Source/grib_api-1.14.0-Source/cmake
-- cmake     3.3.1      /usr/bin/cmake.exe
-- ---------------------------------------------------------
-- Could NOT find Git (missing:  GIT_EXECUTABLE)
-- Performing Test EC_HAVE_C_INLINE
-- Performing Test EC_HAVE_C_INLINE - Success
```

..

```
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Performing Test IEEE_BE
-- Performing Test IEEE_BE - Failed
-- Performing Test IEEE_LE
-- Performing Test IEEE_LE - Success
CMake Error at cmake/ecbuild_check_os.cmake:336 (message):
  ecBuild is untested for this operating system: [CYGWIN] -- refusing to
  continue.  Disable this check with -DDISABLE_OS_CHECK=ON
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/ecbuild_system.cmake:266 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/c/users/username/desktop/grib_api-1.14.0-Source/grib_api-1.14.0-Source/buildagain/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/cygdrive/c/users/username/desktop/grib_api-1.14.0-Source    /grib_api-1.14.0-Source/buildagain/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

What is causing these errors? In `CMakeLists.txt` at line 16, I just see

```
include( ecbuild_system )
```

and at line 266 of `cmake/ecbuild_system.cmake:266` I just see

```
include( ecbuild_check_os )
```

I also don't understand why I get the message `Could NOT find Git (missing:  GIT_EXECUTABLE)`. I already have Git Bash installed and `git.exe` is located at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe
```

I also created environment variables `GIT` and `GIT_EXECUTABLE` to point to that `git.exe` but I still get the error

Comment: The [Microsoft Windows (experimental)](https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=48109524) page seems to indicate building with VisualStudio. Are you sure the CMake build is supposed to work for Cygwin? The `ecBuild is untested for this operating system: [CYGWIN]` message certainly doesn't look encouraging.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer yet, but it's hard enough to express it as a comment:

1. Likely `git` is not found because `git.exe` isn't in system `PATH`. Try to add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\` to system PATH in "My computer" properties
2. Try to locate `ecbuild_check_os.cmake`. Likely they perform some system checks and ban all unknown environments. You can however override this behaviour on your own risk by passing `-DDISABLE_OS_CHECK=ON` among other CMake command line options (e.g. `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`). Certainly the result isn't guaranteed at all and depends on your courage and patience. Post more questions on SO as you go. Then probably you may post your experience and perhaps patches back to the projects authors :)
3. You may try to build the project with Visual Studio (Express) as @EtanReisner suggested, but if you need to build the libraries for Cygwin environment, likely you have to cope with p.2